# manually adding ontology to a repo that originally had no metadata upon import in GraphDB?

Tags: owl, protege, rdfs, graphdb

Recently some queries like the following started failing:

```
@prefix myOnto: <ontology url>

select * where { 
    ?sam ?loves ?greenEggs .
    ?loves rdfs:subPropertyOf myOnto:foodFeals .
}
```

Eventually I realized that the url linked at `@prefix myOnto: <ontology url>` has somehow become unreachable in the past couple days.  So I opened the workbench and imported a local copy, `myOnto.owl`, and re-ran the query, but it still fails.

This leads to the following questions:

1. how to I make GraphDB warn me when I try to import rdf data with no metadata?
2. how do I tell GraphDB, "hey, I just gave you the ontology you need to do inference, so don't worry that the endpoint `@prefix myOnto: <ontology url>` is unreachable right now!"?

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal, but it worked to simply put the originally-imported rdf data in a folder with `myOnto.owl` and import the whole thing to a fresh repository.